# How to preload MongoDB document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing a web application with Node and MongoDB (with mongoose) - I have a collection that has a pre-defined data (images links that the users will choose one of them - they set of the images links is closed and won't be changed during the run of the application) and it need to be joined with other collection. I don't know if it is better to create a collection for this or to save the data in a single JSON file. But because i need to join this collection with other collection I decided to save the data in the DB.

Now the question is how I can create the data in the DB once and each time I raise the Node server the data won't be created again? (something like upsert)? and where is the best place to add this method? in the Schema module or where?

Thanks.

Comment: At startup, you can check if collection exists (or if count() of the collection > 0 is fine too), if doesn't exist, then populate your data.

Comment: I don't want to check each and each one each time. I have a JSON in a file and want to upload it to the DB - if a record is found then update it, otherwise, create it something like upsert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it by running an import command before raising the server (or even after the server is up) - I run the following line which will create the new documents or update the exist documents (according to the _id in the JSON file):

```
mongoimport --db test --collection supported_images --type json --file SupportedImages.json --upsert --jsonArray
```

Thanks everyone.